# How to lump repeated values into the same interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset similar to the below that is spatial.  Has an "ID", "Assay" that comes from an analytical machine, From interval and To interval.  I want to have it look by ID and Assay as it goes down from top to bottom, and find the repeated Assay values and lump them if they are repeating (right after the other).  I tried using groupby and aggregate but ended up with it lumping any Assay value that was similar together, I only want it to put together if its back to back.  Hopefully the example below makes sense.  Thanks in advance!
The result is what I want, but the code won't get me that.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID":    [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5],
    "Assay": [ 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    "From":  [ 7, 8, 9,10, 0, 8,12,15, 0, 5,10,15],
    "To":    [13,14,15,16,17,18,13,100,5,10,15,25]
})
result = df.groupby(["ID", "Assay"]).agg({"From":['first'], "To":['last']})
```

Expected output:

```
          From   To
         first last
ID Assay
1  3         7   14
   4         9   15
   3        10   16
2  3         0   17
   6         8   18
3  4        12  100
5  1         0    5
   1         5   10
   2        10   15
   2        15   25
```

Comment: sorry what do you want, can you show an expecting output

Comment: @DataSciRookie that is what the print(result) if it worked is my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `diff`+`ne`+`cumsum` to create groups out of consecutive Assays; then filter the Assays that are greater than 3 and use `groupby.agg` for aggregation.
Then concatenate this result with the rows that were filtered for the final output:

```py
df['groups'] = df['Assay'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
msk = df['Assay'].ge(3)
tmp = (df[msk].groupby(['ID','Assay', 'groups'], sort=False)
       .agg({'From':'first', 'To':'last'}).reset_index())
out = pd.concat((tmp, df[~msk])).sort_values('groups').drop(columns='groups').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```py
   ID  Assay  From   To
0   1      3     7   14
1   1      4     9   15
2   1      3    10   16
3   2      3     0   17
4   2      6     8   18
5   3      4    12  100
6   5      1     0    5
7   5      1     5   10
8   5      2    10   15
9   5      2    15   25
```

Comment: I want to only update the sections that are greater than 3 and leave the rest but still have it spit out all together, does that make sense?

Comment: ok updated so anything with Assay less than 3 won't change.

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can help you with it or you can take a look at [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) based solution:

```py
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
from convtools import conversion as c


iter_rows = Table.from_csv("input.csv", header=True).into_iter_rows(dict)

# store the converter in a variable for further reuse;
# this is a normal ad hoc function
converter = (
    c.chunk_by(c.item("ID"), c.item("Assay"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "ID": c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item("ID")),
            "Assay": c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item("Assay")),
            "From first": c.ReduceFuncs.First(c.item("From")),
            "To last": c.ReduceFuncs.Last(c.item("To")),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)

iter_new_rows = converter(iter_rows)

assert list(iter_new_rows) == [
 {'ID': '1', 'Assay': '3', 'From first': '7', 'To last': '14'},
 {'ID': '1', 'Assay': '4', 'From first': '9', 'To last': '15'},
 {'ID': '1', 'Assay': '3', 'From first': '10', 'To last': '16'},
 {'ID': '2', 'Assay': '3', 'From first': '0', 'To last': '17'},
 {'ID': '2', 'Assay': '6', 'From first': '8', 'To last': '18'},
 {'ID': '3', 'Assay': '4', 'From first': '12', 'To last': '100'},
 {'ID': '5', 'Assay': '1', 'From first': '0', 'To last': '10'},
 {'ID': '5', 'Assay': '2', 'From first': '10', 'To last': '25'}]

# # or if a csv file is needed
# Table.from_rows(iter_new_rows).into_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: let me try this, I'll have to try to understand it first though.  I don't like using something without understanding having little experience with convtools.  I'll let you know though so thank you!